# Android admob revenue based

Tags: android, admob, revenue

I developed an app called Make Money.

Which means when user taps 10000 times on egg then, I will have to pay user $1.

But I need to get revenue more than $1 to pay them and I earn some.

Now my app is live and I integrated admob ad which gives revenue an average of $0.5 per user. Is there any way to earn more than $1 per user.

Comment: This can be done many ways. 
1)You can server more ads to increase your revenue.
2) Increase the hit of egg instead of just 10000.
3) Show ads after each taps on eggs.
4) Show ads on other pages.

Comment: @Andy I integrated rewarded video for every 500 clicks. I don't want to interrupt more than that.

Comment: @ andy. is any other ad network available other than admob. I don't want to get suspended.

Comment: In that case you have only two option either increase the taps of eggs or reduce the price you pay to user.

Comment: @Andy Developer. I can try with your third point with other ad network if they ban I don't care.

Comment: @ Andy Increase tap is a better Idea I think. Thank you.

Comment: Yes their are many ad networks [see here](https://www.adpushup.com/blog/top-8-best-paying-mobile-ad-networks-you-should-try/)